# Material displacement as (displacement) surface modifer

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, displacement

I have a model that relies on the displacement of the material to get the desired shape, but now I wanted to apply a remesh surface modifier after the displacement and I am having issues with how to proceed.

I know that the material is applied after all surface modifiers so I first tried to add a displacement modifier and remove the displacement from the material. The problem is that I cannot get the modifier to act the same since the available nodes are different. This is roughly how my nodes look like as part of the material:
[image: Material Shader displacement nodes]

Using texture nodes (for the displacement modifier) the Wave texture for example doesnt exist at all. I know it is possible to bake the displacement into a texture and then use it in the displacement modifier but if I want to animate the displacement this becomes a very tedious process.

So I was wondering if it is possible to use the animated displacement nodes from my material as a displacement surface modifier or alternatively if it is possible to first use the shader displacement before the surface modifiers get applied?

Comment: When you talk about surface modifier, do you mean the Displace modifier? The texture are not the same so I guess you need to use some tricks to use them

Comment: Yeah, ideally a displacement modifier but if there is another deform modifier that can keep the same result that would be fine as well.

Comment: You would have to bake the material displacement to an image and use that in the displace modifier

Comment: @AllenSimpson So if I want to animate the displacement I need to bake an image for every frame right?

Comment: I would say yes